# my sql is not launching

Tags: mysql-workbench, sql, mssql

```
mysql-workbench

/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libgdkmm-2.4.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

this error shows up when i run  `mysql-workbench` command line. how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: i have workbench button on the display.but cant open that one

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu you have? How did you install mysql-workbench?

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall?
`sudo apt purge mysql-workbench && sudo apt install mysql-workbench`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a dependency package of `mysql-workbench` was corrupted and now misses a file. According to [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libgdkmm-2.4.so.1) you need to reinstall one package containing `libgdkmm-2.4.so.1`:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgtkmm-2.4-1v5
```